# How do you properly implement a robust stack in C

Tags: c, stack, heap-memory, buffer-overflow

### Prior Knowledge

I've read and understand a bit about stacks and data structures, but couldn't find the answer to this specific question. I know that any programmer worth anything will implement security exception handling beyond the default in their programs.

### Situation

I would like to understand how a program could be written in C that establishes a relatively robust stack with exception handling for some arbitrary case S.
My goal is to discern from this very specific information why (from what I understand) it is always possible to exploit the SEH in a program and execute arbitrary code.

The issue is **not** that I do not understand the concept of overflowing a buffer - I do not understand **why (in very specific, CPU architecture related reasons) the security implemented on the stack (canaries, etc) cannot sufficiently address these issues** (like heap overflows cannot be stopped?).

### Reference Information

"There is no sane way to alter the layout of data within a structure; structures are expected to be the same between modules, especially with shared libraries. Any data in a structure after a buffer is impossible to protect with canaries; thus, programmers must be very careful about how they organize their variables and use their structures. In C and C++, structures with buffers should either be malloc()ed or obtained with new."
- via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Implementations

Also:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2006/08/16/702707.aspx

If anyone knows a good *resource for understanding* this material or can provide a *code snippet*, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Stack of what?  (I can think of some stuff that gets stacked that is quite "robust", but I don't think you're talking about that.)

Comment: C doesn't support exceptions or SEH; so if "robust" means "safe in the presence of exceptions" then the answer is "you're using the wrong language".

Comment: I had no idea. I meant robust like....difficult to exploit I suppose.

Comment: Also note that C doesn't have a stack either. It has function parameters and local variables. A tool (compiler) may convert the C into something else that does have a stack (e.g. assembly), but in that case it's not C anymore.

Comment: SEH is Microsoft's [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx), an extension to C.  It is certainly not Standard C, but then neither are extensions found in the GNU C Compiler.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de5awhsw.aspx) for information about the differences between SEH and C++ exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security of the stack *can* be made secure enough to cope with stack overflows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a89h429(VS.80).aspx

The question as to why you need registered exception handlers (*safe*-SEH) and why normal exception handlers won't cut it is because of the case where you get very large stack overflows.

Let's suppose I have the function which begins

```
try {
   char buffer[N];
   strcpy(&buffer, &attacker);
} __except(...) { }
```

This might translate into the assembly code

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
; GS if you want to here

; install the exception handler:
push lbl_Exceptionhandler
push dword ptr [fs:0]
mov dword ptr[fs:0], esp

; setup the locals inside the stack
sub esp, LOCALS
; GS if you want to here

; call strcpy
lea ecx [ebp + offset_to_buffer];
push ecx
lea edx, [ebp + offset_to_attacker]
push edx
call _strcpy
add esp, 8

; uninstall the locals
mov esp, ebp

; uninstall the exception handler
pop dword ptr [fs:0]

; return
pop ebp

; optionally check GS cookies that we might have also inserted at any point in this function.
call _checksecuritycookie
ret
```

Or in other words, the stack looks like this:

```
RET PTR 
/GS1
SAVED EBP
/GS2
SAVED FS:0
/GS3
LOCAL char buffer[N]
```

GS1, GS2 and GS3 are locations where stack canaries might choose to write the stack cookie. Note that the cookie will only be checked at the end of the function (This is important in computer security. When you introduce a check you need to think not only whether the check will detect the overflow, but whether it will detect it before it is already too late; and that requires thinking where the check will take place. For stack cookies, the cookie is only inspected on function exits, because stack cookies are generally only there to protect the return address, not to protect local variables).

The problem with normal exception handlers is what happens if the attacker buffer is really huge. Let's suppose it's *so* huge it destroys the entire stack, writes onto the guard page for the thread and triggers a fault?

Well, the kernel calls back into ntdll and tells it to sort it's process out, and ntdll's first port of call is to see if there are any registered exception handlers. Now how does it find what exception handler to call? Well, it looks at fs:0, which points to the exception handler on the stack, and calls the exception handler pointer. Except that exception handler's on the stack that the attacker just destroyed.

Oops. Now the attacker has control of EIP and you lose.

Safe-SEH solves this problem by noting that the list of exception handlers that you might ever want to call is in fact a finite list entirely determined at compile time. By burning this list into the PE file itself, ntdll has a chance to double check that the exception handler that it should jump to is, in fact, a real exception handler and not the cause of some evil attacker's plot to take over your EIP.

There's a cost to Safe-SEH (hence why it is opt in), but that cost is that it becomes more expensive to catch an exception, since ntdll will now do more work before your exception handler takes over.

Despite this, my advice is that SafeSEH should always be on. Making it easier to lose your customer's credit card details because your app is critically performance dependent on the speed of throwing exceptions suggests a mentality so horrendously broken in the developers mind that they should be immediately put into a cannon and fired into the sun to avoid their awful code from damaging society.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to implement a stack in C is to use a linked list. For example:

```
struct stack_entry {
    struct stack_entry *previous;
    /* other fields for the actual data */
}

struct stack_entry *stack_top = NULL;

void push(struct stack_entry *entry) {
    entry->previous = stack_top;
    stack_top = entry;
}

struct stack_entry *pop(void) {
    struct stack_entry *entry;

    entry = stack_top;
    if(entry != NULL) stack_top = entry->previous;
    return entry;
}
```

This is as robust and difficult to exploit as any other normal code.

Comment: I think the question is about implementing the C runtime stack, not implementing a stack in C.

Comment: I think the question doesn't make too much sense; which is why I've written 2 different answers based on 2 possible interpretations of the question.. ;-)

Comment: @Brendan: Stack canaries, SEH and buffer overflows and exploits mentioned in the question make it pretty unambiguously about the stack (i.e. to one that ESP points to), and not about implementing push-pop stacks.

Comment: @templatetypedef - Yet the OP never said this, even when directly asked.

Comment: @SecurityMatt: The words "how a program could be written in C that establishes a relatively robust stack" are the reason I posted this answer. The mention of SEH and buffer overflows are the reason I posted the other answer. I can't understand why people have so much difficulty with concept of "hedging bets".

Answer (score 0):

If you're not implementing a stack in C, but are implementing a C compiler (in any language), then..

It would be possible to create a C compiler that detects programming errors and generates safe code. For example, for every read or write the compiler could insert checks to ensure that the read or write is contained within one storage area (e.g. and you're not trying to write 4 bytes at the end of an array of char or something); where a signal is raised (e.g. "SIGSEGV") if one of these checks fail.

Due to the nature of C, these checks would involve scanning things like the heap, and it'd require more code to be insert to track the sizes of things on the stack.

The main reason this hasn't been implemented is that it'd create massive performance problems, and would therefore defeat the purpose of using C to begin with.

However, there are debugging tools (e.g. valgrind) that do this type of checking by running the application inside a virtual machine (where the virtual machine tracks the sizes of storage areas and is able to check reads/writes before they're performed).

Comment: Java, on the other hand, accomplishes this with relatively low overhead.  As do a number of other environments.  The main issue is with pointers than can be arbitrarily manipulated, and aliasing, dead pointers, etc.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, some languages are designed for this sort of thing, but C was designed with other goals in mind. In some ways, expecting a relatively low level language like C to be "safe" is like expecting a relatively high level language (Java, Python, etc) to be good for things like kernel development.

Comment: Actually, you could do some pretty good kernel development with Java, given the right compiler and JVM.